# Количество Н в отглагольных прилагательных

Tags: прилагательные

Я прочитала, что в отглагольных прилагательных всегда пишется -н-, если в слове нет суффиксов -ова-, -ева-, -ирова-. Но почему тогда в словах "воспитанный" и "сдержанный" пишется -нн-?

Comment: Потому что читать нужно всё правило, а не его часть:
http://uchimcauchitca.blogspot.ru/2013/10/13.html

Answer (score 1):

НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных пишется **по формальному правилу четырёх признаков:**

1) наличие приставки; 2) наличие суффиксов -ова-, -ева-, -ирова и т. д. 
3) наличие зависимых слов; 4) образование от глагола сов. вида.

Воспитать ― сов. вид, сдержать ― приставка и сов. вид.