# "Прощёное воскресенье" — от какого глагола образовано прилагательное

Tags: словообразование

В комментарии к [вопросу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435913/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%9D-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) о количестве "н" Людмила привела [ссылку](http://uchimcauchitca.blogspot.ru/2013/10/13.html#more) на правила, авторы которых, по-видимому, считают, что прилагательное в словосочетании ***Прощёное воскресенье*** образовано от глагола ***простить*** (по их мнению, оно происходит от глагола совершенного вида), то есть они думают, что это прилагательное, образованное от причастия ***прощённое***, которое принято писать с одной Н, но означает оно при этом то же, что и это причастие. (Повторюсь, что я не ручаюсь за их ход мыслей, но так их трактую, возможно, и ошибочно.)

*Как вы считаете, они правы или нет?* Я вот думаю, что это слово образовано всё же не от ***простить***, а от ***прощать***. Если так, тогда всё очень просто: *Прощёное воскресенье — это воскресенье, в которое **прощают**.* А не *которое **простили***, как кажется, если считать, что оно от слова ***простить***. Если от ***прощать***, тогда оно сразу становится прилагательным, минуя стадию причастия.

Comment: Что Вы, shampar, "воскресенье" в данном случае просто день недели, а не как воскресение, например, из мёртвых или Лазаря.

Comment: Это же не языческий праздник, а христианский. И у христиан воскресение до сих пор (и так будет всегда) оно считается первым днём в неделе. Никаких других «Прощёных» праздников нет. Так что у Вас — противоречие.

Comment: Не знаю, тем не менее русский язык он общий для православных и нет, должны быть общие стандарты. Вот, например, на Нацкорпусе всего три примера с И против пятидесяти двух с Ь. С Ь и у Чехова, и у Бунина даже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошая иллюстрация вторичности всяких правил и циркуляров по отношению к живому языку.

Думаю, что выведение этого слова непосредственно из глагольных форм - ложный след: связывание слова "воскресенье" со *страдательным причастием* на какой-либо фантастической стадии транформации такого причастия ведёт к странному смыслу - будто само это воскресенье можно как-то "прощать". Логичнее связать это слово с существительным "прощение": воскресенье, в которое *просят прощения* (простят или не простят - вопрос отдельный), то есть **связанное с "прощением"** (в этом прилагательном одно "н"; вариант же "прощенское" имел бы пренебрежительный оттенок).

Answer (score 2):

```
 по их мнению, оно происходит от глагола совершенного вида, то есть 
 они думают, что это прилагательное, образованное от причастия 
 прощённое, которое принято писать с одной Н, но означает оно при этом 
 то же, что и это причастие.
```

Нет, Артём, авторы этих правил так не считают, они просто относят их к исключениям без объяснений: придАное, смышлёный, конченый, назвАный, посажёный, Прощёное воскресенье. А все исключения, как известно, относятся к традиционным написаниям, и эти тоже.

Пишутся с одной Н **соотносительные** с причастными формами прилагательные в составе следующих устойчивых сочетаний: конченый человек (но оконченный разговор), названый брат (но названный в честь брата), названая сестра, посажёный отец (но посаженный в кресло отец), посажёная мать, Прощёное воскресенье (но прощённый поступок). В некоторых справочниках отмечается, что такова традиционная церковная языковая практика. Я, например, своим детям в школе говорила, что это прилагательные с переносным значением в устойчивых сочетаниях, вроде бы все понимали.

Comment: *Нет, Артём, авторы этих правил так не считают...* Как именно? По крайней мере, этот пример у них в графе "образовано от глаголов совершенного вида". А в данном случае какой это может быть глагол кроме "простить"?

Answer (score 1):

Вас что больше интересует, что думали авторы этих материалов, когда их писали? Или как оно образовалось, это исключение, на самом деле?
Первое даже обсуждать не хочу, чужая душа - потемки.

А вот что касается "исключений"... Сложный это вопрос. Ведь это только в более или менее современной грамматике и при современной орфографии возможна подобная формулировка в отношении причастий и прилагательных, что в одном случае НН, в другом Н... И это при том, что граница не всегда обозначена. 
Но раньше-то такое разделение вообще не было чем-то значимым. 
Слово "прощеное" вообще здесь имеет смысл не пассива (воскресение, которое прощено), а скорее актива ("прощающее" воскресение). Уже одно это говорит, что общие подходы просто неприменимы.

Насколько понимаю, исключение это возникло по причине переосмысления заимствования из церковнославянского всего термина - с последующей его адаптацией. В этот день совершался "чин прощения", а монахи, получившие прощение, назывались **прощеными**. Отсюда и пошло. В этом смысле вполне можно считать, что слово выведено из глагола именно совершенного вида (монахов **простили**), но само определение является прилагательным (здесь это качество, а не состояние). Но вот беда, было это так давно, что грамматика, способная дифференцировать причастие и прилагательное, равно как и совершенный и несовершенный вид, просто не существовала. Поэтому гораздо проще отнести этот случай к обусловленным традицией исключением, чем докапываться до сути через дебри потерявших актуальность реалий.

Comment: Всё-то дело как раз в том, что это вообще не исключение. Ну что за чушь: будто бы само воскресенье прощено!

Comment: Я же писал об этом. Ну не было в те времена такого явного разделения на страдательный и действительный залог. А почему не исключение-то?

Comment: Простите, проскочил это место. А откуда у Вас эти сведения про монахов? Можете подтвердить какой-нибудь ссылкой? Если это правда, тогда действительно название воскресенья могло пойти от определения к монахам, и тогда это действительно исключение. Простите ещё раз, что плохо прочитал!